# How to find and delete previously created certificates based on their dns name using powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

I can create a self signed certificate with PowerShell:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate –DnsName www.test.com -CertStoreLocation “cert:\LocalMachine\My”
```

Because this is an automated test scenario, I must allow multiple runs. Next time I (which is a completely separate session) would like to find all certificates with dns name www.test.com, and completely wipe them. It could be more than one, of course with different thumbprint, etc.

Unfortunatelly I can not find any PowerShell command removes certificates. I suppose I should query based on dns, then in a loop remove...

**Question**

Can this task solved at all entirely in Powershell? (remove all certificates with given dns name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple oneliner for this :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object {$_.DnsNameList -contains 'www.domain.org'} | Remove-Item
```

Remove-Item is the command used to remove a certificate.

Comment: Thanks, this is it, tested.

Answer (score 5):

If you have PowerShell v3 or greater this becomes very simple, as PS3 introduced the `-DnsName` parameter to the Certificate provider options of `Get-ChildItem`. This will find and delete anything with the DNSName of www.test.com:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -Recurse -DnsName 'www.test.com' | Remove-Item
```

It even supports wildcards, so if you have several certificates that you need to clean up with similar names such as 'mailproxy.test.com', 'www.test.com', and 'ftp.test.com' you could run this:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\ -Recurse -DnsName '*.test.com' | Remove-Item
```

Comment: This is a way better solution as the one I provided (I was unaware of the DnsName parameter in Get-ChildItem.)